# Mailgun lacks support for ASCII Spanish language characters (ñ)

Tags: node.js, mailgun

Mailgun seems to reject any email containing Spanish language characters. Is this desired functionality, or an oversight? I've tried various uses of ñ and nothing seems to be accepted. If this is a bug, I'll submit a ticket, but I couldn't find any other mention of this issue on the web.

If there are any recommendations, I'm open to switching to any mail service that has this support.

The module in use: https://github.com/1lobby/mailgun-js

API Email Validation Docs: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-email-validation.html

The specific character to test: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/enie-spanish-enye-lowercase-letter-n-tilde-ascii-code-164.html

Comment: That character is not in ASCII. Also, "extended ASCII" is just a term for character sets that include ASCII's characters 00-7F for compatibility. What is probably more helpful is the *actual* character set being used.

Comment: You may want to provide a code sample too that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I confirm this behaviour. What's more, mailgun doesn't seem to log anything in their domain log (I was expecting it to log some sort of rejection message, but at least an indication that the email had been received by mailgun.